# Using after_validation with an if or clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can someone please point me to the right direction.

I'm using after_validation to compete geocoding and I wanted to know how I can tact on an or || option to an if clause.

This works as intended

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
```

But this doesn't

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed? || :zipcode_changed?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use Thilo's `Proc` approach then you can add your own custom method and use that:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_or_zip_changed?
private
  def address_or_zip_changed?
    address_changed? || zipcode_changed?
  end
end
```

This may (or may not) read better and is handy if you need the same compound condition on multiple validations.

Comment: You are a lovely person! I've decided to go with your implementation since creating a private method is more readable to me. Thanks you :)

Comment: I always prefer to write separate method over proc as suggested in this answer. It looks more readable to me.

Comment: Is that a typo, and should the 3rd-last line line actually read `:address_changed? || :zipcode_changed?`?

Comment: @StephenLead Yes a typo but the fix is the other way around (lost a stray colon): `address_changed? || zipcode_changed?`. It should be calling the "changed" methods for the attributes, not using symbols.

Answer (score 3):

> :if - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should occur (e.g. :if => :allow_validation, or :if => Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step > 2 }). The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a true or false value.

So try a proc:

```
if: Proc.new { |a| a.address_changed? || a.zipcode_changed? }
```

Comment: Thanks Thilo. I'm especially grateful that you linked the theory behind the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using :if

```
validates :email, :unique=> true, :if => Proc.new { email.present? }
```

or you could also use lambda

```
validates :email, :unique=> true, :if => lambda { email.present? }
```